# Old wordpress Ajax running even though jQuery is changed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, event-handling

I changed the trigger for some Ajax from on change() of a drop down to on click() of a button but the Ajax is still working for the change on the drop down but not working for the click. Yes, I did save and upload the changes: checked that 32 times. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you empty your browser's cache ?

Comment: Yeah that was it. Thanks!!